# How to Develop an Arbitrary Socket.IO Client that can Connect to a Socket.IO Server

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to develop a **socket.io** application. It is just a simple application like the one on the *Getting Started - Chat application* [tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) in the Socket.IO webpage. But the problem is that, I do not want to have the **socket.io server** serve the client automatically, because I am planning to have a page (in PHP) have a script that can simultaneously be updated by data from a server in real-time using Socket.IO. I just want a certain client that can connect to the server and let them communicate, **not a page served by the socket.io server**.

Is this possible? Can you please give an idea on how can it be done. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain better what you're trying to do.  What do you mean when you say you don't want the server to serve the client automatically?  The client JS code for socket.io support can come from anywhere - it does not have to come from a specific server.  And, likewise, it's totally up to the client when it makes a socket.io connection.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I was referring to the tutorial at the website above, where the socket.io server served the socket.io client. I would like to know if I can have any web page that has a socket.io client script communicate with any socket.io server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That chat tutorial is just a simple deployment where your own web page wants to connect back to the same server that the web page came from.  That is not the only way to do it.

The socket.io client code can be served from anywhere.  You can even link to a CDN and get it from there instead of from your own server.

And, likewise, the client can connect to any compatible server as long as the server is configured to accept a connection from your page.

---

If you're looking for how to connect to a different server, you just specify the URL of the desired host in `io.connect()` like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://www.example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks! It clarified things now. I think this is just what I am looking for.